# AngularJS event for touch equivalent of mouseover

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to make an index-like side bar which will contain the chapters list of a book the user is reading. When a user swipes through the index then the reader will show the selected chapter.
I'm using Angular and i'd like to know how to listen to events like ng-click or ng-mouseover but for touch devices

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module called ngTouch, with which you can probably achieve what you are trying to do.

Here is a link: https://github.com/nglar/ngTouch

Example usage:

```
$scope.onTouchstart = function($event) {
   console.log('touchstart event called');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can use ng-swipe-right or ng-swipe-left:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngSwipeRight
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngSwipeLeft